# pass array from javascript function to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to pass array from function to another in java  script, but when I make it, the browser stalk, I don't know why . here's my code:

```
 function convertToBinary(decNumber){

            var copyDecNum=Number(decNumber);
            var binaryValues= new Array();
            var cnt=0;
               while(copyDecNum.value!=0)
            {
                binaryValues[cnt]=Math.floor(copyDecNum.value%2);
                copyDecNum.value=Math.floor(copyDecNum.value/2);
                cnt++;

            }
            binaryValues[cnt]=copyDecNum%2;
            viewResult(binaryValues,decNumber);



        }

        function viewResult(binaryValues,decNumber){

          alert("here"+binaryValues.length);           //here's the problem
          }
```

can someone help??

Comment: What is this line for `binaryValues[cnt]=copyDecNum%2;`? I understand, that your trying to convert decimal numbers into binary. And the algorithm seems right but what do expect from this line? If you want to append it as last loop shouldn't it be `binaryValues[cnt]=copyDecNum.value%2;` ?

Comment: yes u r right, it dones't have any meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert a decimal number to binary use the following,

```
var dec2bin = function (num) {
  return +(num.toString(2)) //convert number to binary string, then make that a number
}
```

Comment: there's nothing strange in this. I've just utilized what the language provides. Ref: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Answer (score 0):

Use `copyDecNum` instead of `copyDecNum.value` in your code.

Comment: I need the value, so I have to use .value